# How to create empty array because of Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using datatables. The call to the tables are menu based. It is possible that there are no records fetched by the SQL statement so the result is nothing. When that happens the Datatable returns an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

How do I prevent this from happening? I can't find any working example or solution on the internet.

My SQL code to fetch the json data:

```
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result(); //only works when nd_mysli is set on the server!

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dataset = array(0); 

    $array[] = $row;
}

$dataset = array(
    
    "echo" => 1,
    "totalrecords" => count($array),
    "totaldisplayrecords" => count($array),
    "data" => $array,
);

echo json_encode($dataset);
```

Comment: That sounds like a JavaScript error, do you have any javascript to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we're talking about `$array` then yes you can. There are two main ways to do it:

### Declare the variable

You can declare the variable *before* your `while` loop as an empty array: `$array = []`

```
$array = [];

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dataset = array(0); 
    $array[] = $row;
}

$dataset = array(
    "echo"                => 1,
    "totalrecords"        => count($array),
    "totaldisplayrecords" => count($array),
    "data"                => $array,
);

echo json_encode($dataset);
```

### `null` coalescing

In your output you can use the `null` coalescing operator to set a default in the event that `$array` doesn't exist: `$array ?? null`

**Method 1**

Will produce warnings for the `count` functions:

```
$dataset = array(
    "echo"                => 1,
    "totalrecords"        => count($array),
    "totaldisplayrecords" => count($array),
    "data"                => $array ?? [],
);
```

**Method 2**

This is the way it should be done:

```
$array   = $array ?? [];
$dataset = array(
    "echo"                => 1,
    "totalrecords"        => count($array),
    "totaldisplayrecords" => count($array),
    "data"                => $array,
);
```